# How open stream or base64 of excel file by Office.Interop.Excel C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, com, office-interop

I'm using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` to convert excel to pdf. It works very well with excel file path. But is that possible to open `Stream` or `Base64` of Excel by `Interop.Excel` and save to pdf (`Stream` or `Base64`, not pdf file path).

I have searched on internet, but it seems like I can only do that by Visual Basic: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d1a49488-02df-4f8b-bf43-10b7b4ed5b63/open-excel-file-from-stream?forum=vbgeneral

```cs
var thisFileWorkbook = excelApplication.ExcelApplication.Workbooks.Open(excelFilePath); // Open function param is a string ?
string newPdfFilePath = Path.Combine(
    Path.GetDirectoryName(excelFilePath),
    $"{Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(excelFilePath)}.pdf");

thisFileWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat(
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFixedFormatType.xlTypePDF,
    newPdfFilePath); // Save to pdf file path
```

Any advice is welcome!

Comment: In any .NET language (VB.NET included) the Open method only takes a string as input: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.workbooks.open?view=excel-pia the answer to this link seems quite wrong. You can use other 3rd party libraries for that, but that's not Excel itself.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. So if I want to convert base64 of excel file to base64 of pdf. I have to decode base64 to excel file, convert to pdf, and encode to base64, right?

Comment: @SimonMourier anyway, please copy your comment to `Answer`, I will vote for your answer. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In any .NET language (VB.NET included) the [Open method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.workbooks.open?view=excel-pia) only takes a `string` as input. The answer to your link seems quite wrong, I don't see how that could work with a FileStream (or a Stream).

You can use other 3rd party libraries for that, but not Excel itself.